# How can I have the date and time displayed in English without changing my locale settings?

Tags: 16.04, language-support, time, date

I am in Nairobi, Kenya (EAT) and my Date and Time are displayed in Afaan Oromoo. I want to change this to English without having to change my locale.

```
LANG=en_IE.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="om_KE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="om_KE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="om_KE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="om_KE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="om_KE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="om_KE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="om_KE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="om_KE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="om_KE.UTF-8"
```

That is what my locale displays.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. Any leads??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the value of the `LC_TIME` locale category only, you can run this command:

```
sudo update-locale LC_TIME=en_IE.UTF-8
```

Will hopefully take effect at next login.